# AS does not install Apk of my Application on emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

> 07-13 06:05:42.800 1137-1137/? E/cutils: Failed to read
>   /data/.layout_version: No such file or directory
>
> 07-13 06:05:43.200 1133-1133/? E/libEGL:
>   load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed:
>   library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
>   I'm getting these errors while trying to install the .apk file of my android application on my android emulator:
>
> 07-13 06:05:45.130 1136-1207/? E/AudioFlinger: no wake lock to update!
>
> 07-13 06:05:45.200 1136-1136/? E/AudioFlinger: int
>   android::load_audio_interface(const char*, audio_hw_device_t**)
>   couldn't load audio hw module audio.r_submix (No such file or
>   directory)
>
> 07-13 06:05:45.200 1133-1133/? E/SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not
>   found

What could be causing them?

Comment: The error looks like logcat, but if your app was not installed, there is nothing related to the problem. Do you see errors in "Event Log" tab in Android studio or in "Run" tab?

Comment: On Run Tab 07/13 12:45:57: Launching app
Client not ready yet..

Comment: on Event log 12:40:51 PM Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
12:45:56 PM Gradle build finished in 5m 4s 917ms

Answer (score 0):

`While creating emulator check the option "Use Host GPU" at the bottom and try..`

Make sure that your TARGET API of your project is the same as your EMULATOR's version.

E.g If your project is targetting 4.4.2 then make sure your emulator is set to 4.4.2

Comment: on Event Log 12:40:51 PM Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
12:45:56 PM Gradle build finished in 5m 4s 917ms